# spring boot serves index.html despite the resource handler mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a vuejs + spring boot app. All was working fine, but suddenly got this issue - requests to files in `/js/`, `/css/`, `/img/` are returning the `index.html` content despite having a resource mapping pointing to `classpath:/static`.

Can't trance the original change which lead to the appearance of this problem. front-end works fine by itself (tried deploying to `surge` & `zeit now`), so i suppose the problem is that spring boot ignores the resource mapping.

spring boot v`2.1.2`

**WebMvcConfig:**

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    String baseApiPath = "/api";

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/**/*.css", "/**/*.html", "/**/*.js", "/**/*.png", "/**/*.ttf")
                .setCachePeriod(0)
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/")
                .setCachePeriod(0)
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/index.html")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {

                    @Override
                    protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                        if (resourcePath.startsWith(baseApiPath) || resourcePath.startsWith(baseApiPath.substring(1))) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        return location.exists() && location.isReadable() ? location : null;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

in `index.html` links like this `<script src=/js/chunk-vendors.b7114b0e.js></script><script src=/js/app.5c7ddca5.js></script>` returning the `index.html` itself.

Comment: You've mapped `/**` to `classpath:/static/index.html`. `/**` will match every request so it'll serve `index.html`. What were you trying to achieve with your configuration?

Comment: whops, right, simply overseen it. however removing `/**` doesn't solve the prob.

Comment: Just FYI, as it's stated [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) Spring Boot serves static files out-of-the-box.  Maybe that autoconfiguration is messing up your mapping?

Comment: yeah i know about that. implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` adds to that autoconf but not completely overwrites it. By now the problem is solved, but weirdly, i didn't get the cause - was messing about disabling / enabling conf, etc and suddenly it just works. tried reverting 10+ steps -> still working, got back to this config -> working. very weird issue.